# Cannot apply custom CSS via theme settings

Tags: 7, theming

With Drupal 7.x and the Whitejazz theme, I want to apply custom CSS styles to some elements. This theme has the option to include custom CSS styles by specifying the path to the CSS file (in Appearance > Settings).

> [image: screenshot]

I created the folder and uploaded my file, specified path, but this doesn't work for me, even after clearing the cache. I can apply my styles using the *CSS injector* module without a problem, but I want to find out why I can not set this using the theme settings.

Comment: If the custom stylesheet field shown above is provided by the theme, the failiure to import the css may simply be an issue with the theme's implementation.

Comment: @autopoietic Yes, it was an issue with the theme's implementation.

Comment: Please do not edit answers directly into questions. Use answer box for that.

Comment: How I can add answer if you deleted it from my post?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in a theme. Please report and discuss all bugs in the module's issue queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct method is below.
The theme maintainer replied me, there is a wrong path entry in template.php file, line 15

```
  if (theme_get_setting('whitejazz_uselocalcontent')) {
    $local_content = path_to_theme() . '/' . theme_get_setting('whitejazz_localcontentfile');
    if (file_exists($local_content)) {
      drupal_add_css($local_content);
    }
  }
```

At the moment whitejazz (template.php) search for the CSS file in its own themefolder Whitejazz. So CSS should be placed anywhere **inside** the themefolder Whitejazz, i.e. 'css/headers.css' But if I want move the css file to an another place in the drupal rootfolder, then I have to remove in template.php on line 15 this path_to_theme() . '/' ., that is:

```
if (theme_get_setting('whitejazz_uselocalcontent')) {
//   $local_content = path_to_theme() . '/' . theme_get_setting('whitejazz_localcontentfile');
   $local_content = theme_get_setting('whitejazz_localcontentfile');
   if (file_exists($local_content)) {
      drupal_add_css($local_content);
   }
}
```

So any of these two methods works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you forget to add a reference statement in your theme's info file.
like this:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/layout.css
```

After that, need to clean the cache.

Comment: It looks like 'White Jazz' theme provides its own field for custom css, implying it does not need to be included in the .info file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the theme, the template assumes that the custom css is within the theme folder:

```
path_to_theme() . '/' . theme_get_setting('whitejazz_localcontentfile');
```

If you want to provide custom CSS in this manner the you need to provide a relative path from the theme folder, eg `test.css`, rather than `sites/all/theme/whitejazz/headers.css`. I have tested this and it works fine.

The description provided by the theme is therefore misleading, but this theme is minimally maintained in any case.